# Angular model doesn't scope to variable within child DOM element?

Tags: angularjs

I have this markup:

```
<div data-ng-model="currentUser.attributes">
    <div>{{username}}</div>
</div>
```

And this is a stripped down version of my controller:

```
$scope.username = "Alice";
$scope.currentUser = {
    attributes: {
        username: "Bob"
    }
};
```

I want `Bob` to display, but instead, I am getting `Alice`.  It works just fine if I use this:

```
{{currentUser.attributes.username}}
```

But I don't want to have to scope down to this variable's properties every time I want to access something.  How can I get the element to exist within the scope of `currentUser.attributes`?

Comment: Since your $scope.currentUser object doesn't have an attributes property, angular will dynamically create that property for you. What exactly are you trying to achieve by introducing the .attributes property?

Comment: Fixed.  Like I said, I was only transcribing a simplified version of my controller.

Comment: I understand what you were hoping to achieve now. I added an answer that describes how you might achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Bob just do the the following in your HTML.

```
<div>{{current user}}</div>//IGNORE THIS

<div>{{currentUser.attributes.username}}</div>//UPDATED CORRECTED
```

UPDATED based on clarification.

So in Knockout you do this

```
<p data-bind="with: currentUser.attributes">
    <div data-bind="text: userName></div>
    <div data-bind="text: login></div>
    <div data-bind="text: bhalBlah></div>
    <div data-bind="text: yaddaYadda></div>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.applyBindings({
        currentUser: {
           attributes: {
                userName  : 'Bob',
                login     : 't@e',
                blahBlah  : 'ttttt',
                yaddaYadda: 'x'
           }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Same thing in AngularJS would be

```
<p ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>{{currentUser.attributes.userName}}</div>
    <div>{{currentUser.attributes.login}}</div>
    <div>{{currentUser.attributes.blahBlah}}</div>
    <div>{{currentUser.attributes.yaddaYadda}}</div>
</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope =  {
     currentUser: {
           attributes: {
                userName  : 'Bob',
                login     : 't@e',
                blahBlah  : 'ttttt',
                yaddaYadda: 'x'
           }
    };
});
</script>
```

In this the question is how to avoid how not to repeat the part the full property paths between ** as shown below in angular.

```
  **currentUser.attributes.**userName
  **currentUser.attributes.**login
  **currentUser.attributes.**blahBlah
  **currentUser.attributes.**yaddaYadda
```

Here is one way see [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4fSESqBJejPC1XUR9BkT?p=preview) using ng-init which reduces 'currentUser.attributes' to just 'attr'.

### With just attr.<properties> repeated

{{attr.userName}}
        {{attr.login}}
        {{attr.blahBlah}}
        {{attr.yaddaYadda}}

Another way is you restructure your object and flatten it on the $scope. 
This is not recommended because now you are putting primitives on to the $scope and are widening the scope with $scope.userName = currentUser.attributes.username. Also your 'repetitive' code is still there just in the Javascript.

In lieu of ng-init

```
ng-init="attr = currentUser.attributes"
```

You could also do this in controller

```
$scope.attr = currentUser.attributes;
```

Comment: it's not that I want `Bob`, I can do that, I just don't want to have to drilldown through the property every time I want to access a member.  It can be really heavy syntatically.

Comment: Can you put down in terms of code/html what you expect ?

Comment: Exactly what was in my original post except with a working solution instead of `data-ng-model`.  Is there any ng-attribute or other solution to be able to avoid typing out `currentUser.attributes` every single time?  If I make any structural changes, I will have to change every single instance of `currentUser.attributes` or else my application will break.

Knockout.js has the `with` binding to solve this issue.

Comment: I understand now after your reference to knockout 'with'. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't think you should really do this, it is what you're asking for. You can essentially mimic `with` by using `ng-repeat` on an array that you populate with the relevant object. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in [currentUser.attributes]">
    {{ user.username }}
</div>
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/svwYEeWMQXjuAnLkr9Vz?p=preview

Other possible solutions would be to have a service or controller that has functions to get the attributes and return them, cleaning up the syntax of your HTML and making it easier to change backend stuff without breaking your frontend. Your choice.

**Edit:** I noticed you actually expect to be able to do `{{ username }}` and get the relevant info, if that's really what you want then I suggest my second proposal. Create functions that return the relevant info.

```
<div>
    {{ getCurrentUserName() }}
</div>

$scope.getCurrentUserName = function() {
    return $scope.currentUser.attributes.username;
};
```

Your call, take it or leave it.

Comment: Thanks, I guess there's no elegant way of doing it, but it does work.  I'm surprised Google hasn't provided this functionality.

Comment: This is a good answer. I understand what you we're trying to achieve now. You could also look into using directives to achieve something along these lines. But the functional solution is a good first start.

Answer (score 1):

This post really got me thinking. I had a theory on how to accomplish this using a directive.

Came up with a proof of concept on plnkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/OJDhpJ1maEdSoPvlbiRA/

If I understand correctly, you want to only display the properties within a given block of your struct.

Given the following struct:

```
$scope.currentUser = {
    attributes: {
      username: 'Batman',
      age: '99',
      address: {
        street: 'Bat Cave'
      }
    }
  };
```

You want to scope things down with something like:

```
<div scope-with="currentUser.attributes">
    Username: {{username}}<br />
    Age: {{age}}
    <div scope-with="address">
       Street: {{street}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('mymodule', [])

.directive('scopeWith', function($interpolate){


  return {

    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      scopeWith: '='
    },
    transclude: 'element',
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, linker) {

      return function( scope, element, attr) {

        var childScope,
            parent = element.parent(),
            withBlock = null
        ;

        scope.$watch('scopeWith', function(val){
          childScope = scope.$new();

          angular.forEach(val, function(val, prop){
            childScope[prop] = val;  
          });


          if(withBlock) {
            withBlock.el.remove();
            withBlock.scope.$destroy();
          }

          linker(childScope, function(clone){

            withBlock = {};
            parent.append(clone);
            withBlock.el = clone;
            withBlock.scope = childScope;

          });


        }, true);

      };

    }

  };
```

Comment: Decent solution, and if the markup was used throughout your application you could create a template instead -- within the template your bindings would be able to look just as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{currentUser.username}}` to show Bob.

The ng-model on the div is irrelevant as it only applies to input elements.

Comment: I know it is useless since it doesn't do anything.  I am looking for a way to avoid fully qualifying every single variable I use.